# Django / FactoryBoy - unable to generate instance for abstract models

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am writing tests for a Django application and I am currently running into the following problem:

I have this (abstract) model:

```
class HeroContent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True,
        default=None)
    subtitle = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True, null=True,
        default=None)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

For which I created the following factory:

```
class HeroContentFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = HeroContent
        abstract = True

    title = factory.Faker('company')
    subtitle = factory.Faker('company')
```

I consulted the [documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/orms.html?highlight=abstract#the-djangomodelfactory-subclass) on how to handle abstract models, but when I run the following test:

```
class HeroContentFactoryTest(TestCase):

    def test_init(self):
        hero_content = HeroContentFactory()
```

The following error gets raised:

`FactoryError: Cannot generate instances of abstract factory HeroContentFactory; Ensure HeroContentFactory.Meta.model is set and HeroContentFactory.Meta.abstract is either not set or False.`

But this seems to go directly against the course recommended in the official documentation, 
which states that when

```
If a DjangoModelFactory relates to an abstract model, be sure to declare the DjangoModelFactory as abstract
```

Removing the `abstract = True` setting from the Factory

Raises the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create'`

calling `.create` on a abstract model should fail ofcourse, but now I am wondering what would be the proper way to test these kind of models using factory - especially sinds the course suggested in the documentation is not working for me.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit from `HeroContentFactory` into `HeroContentConcreteFactory`, which will be tied to a subclass of `HeroContent`, which will be a concrete model. You can't instantiate from an abstract model nor abstract factory.